# Limiting Builder Pattern Parameter

Tags: design-patterns

I have simple builder example to illustrate the question "How can I stop a builder parameter from being set twice?"

```
SimpleVehicle kia = new SimpleVehicle.Builder().setPrice(100).setType("Kia").setPrice(120).build();

System.out.println(kia.toString());
```

The price has been set to 100 and then again to 120. Is it possible to prevent this? The print returns - SimpleVehicle{price=120, type='Kia'} which is what the builder was asked to do.

The SimpleVehicle class is

```
public class SimpleVehicle {

private long price;
private String type;

private SimpleVehicle(Builder builder) {
    this.price = builder.price;
    this.type = builder.type;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SimpleVehicle{" +
            "price=" + price +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public static class Builder {

    private long price;
    private String type;

    public Builder(){

    }

    public Builder setPrice(long value) {
        this.price = value;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setType(String value) {
        this.type = value;
        return this;
    }

    public SimpleVehicle build() {
        return new SimpleVehicle(this);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could always throw an exception if the value has already been set, just have additional flags like `private bool _priceSet` and test whether it's been set to true and throw.

If you want to actually prevent such access in the first place, the only way would be by offering separate interfaces.

```
public interface IBuilder
{
  IBuilderWithPrice SetPrice(long value);
  IBuilderWithType SetType(string value);
}

public interface IBuilderWithPrice
{
  IBuilderWithPriceAndType SetType(string value);
}

public interface IBuilderWithType
{
  IBuilderWithPriceAndType SetPrice(long value);
}
```

You could choose where to put the build method, depending on whether you need a certain combination of values to construct the type correctly.

Obviously the separate interface technique makes the interface nice and fluent and restricts usage how you want - but it adds a huge amount of extra code to consider.